# How to load a JSON onto a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I need to pass to a Object a NSArray. In order it can show that array as Tags on the Interface, It works properly when using a manually added NSArray, But not i need to load a NSArray With a JSON Array Called Subjects I've done some code but it's not working out.

Also gives an error:

```
/Users/eddwinpaz/Documents/iOS-apps/mobile-app/mobile-app/UserDetailViewController.m:86:26: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'insertObject:atIndex:'
```

This is the Code I'm Using

```
        NSArray *subject_tag;

        for (NSString* subject in [responseObject valueForKey:@"subjects"]) {

            [subject_tag insertObject:subject];
        }


        CGRect frame = Scroller.frame;

        frame.origin.y = 100;
        frame.origin.x = 5;
        frame.size.height = 150;

        UIPillsView *pillsView = [[UIPillsView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        [pillsView generatePillsFromStringsArray:subject_tag];

        [Scroller addSubview:pillsView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 problems here.

1. You never initialize your array, you only declare it. (This one is not actually causing the error and would just cause the code to fail silently once you fixed the next 2)
2. `NSArrays` are immutable. Elements cannot be added or removed after initialization. You need to use an `NSMutableArray` for this.
3. The method you are using does not exist in `NSMutableArray` anyway.

Here is what you should be doing:

```
    NSMutableArray *subject_tag = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSString* subject in [responseObject valueForKey:@"subjects"]) {

        [subject_tag addObject:subject];
    }
```

Comment: thanks. It works Now i Understand. Thanks also for the explanation. I feel less stupid now :)